# Trying to post a table of products with Websocket and Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I was trying to make a table of products with websocket for the "real-time" response, just learn about it and i was trying to upgrade an old project to this method, clearly i didn't make it and that's why im here

I really dont know the issue here so im kinda lost, the idea is that the user enters 3 inputs (title, price, thumbnail) and with websocket it would display below as a table using bootstrap properties in real time for all the users to see.

Here is my code so far:

html

```
    <div class="container mt-3 bg-dark">
        <h1 class="text-center text-primary">Ingrese datos</h1>

        <form class="text-light">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title"><b>Producto</b></label>
                <input id="title" type="text" name="title">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price"><b>Precio</b></label>
                <input id="price" type="number" name="price">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="thumbnail"><b>Thumbnail</b></label>
                <input id="thumbnail" type="text" name="thumbnail">
            </div>
        
            <button id="send">Postear</button>
        
        </form>

        <h2 class="text-center text-danger">Historial</h2>

        <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
```

js for the products

```
const socket = io();

let title = document.getElementById("title")
let price = document.getElementById("price")
let thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail")
let btn = document.getElementById("send")
let output = document.getElementById("output")


btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    socket.emit("products", {
        title: title.value,
        price: price.value,
        thumbnail: thumbnail.value
    });
});

socket.on("products", function (data) {
    output.innerHTML += `
    <table class="table table-dark">
                <tr class="text-warning">
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Thumbnail</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ${data.title}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${data.price}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${data.thumbnail}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
    `
})
```

js for the server

```
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 8080)

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))

const server = app.listen(app.get("port"), ()=>{
    console.log("server on port", app.get("port"))
})

const SocketIO = require("socket.io")
const io = SocketIO(server)

io.on("connection", (socket)=>{
    console.log("new connection", socket.id)

    socket.on("products", (data) => {
        io.sockets.emit("products", data);
    })
})
```

The problem right now is that when i click the send button it doesnt do anything, the server gives me a new connection and thats it, started today with websocket so i assume that the problem is something very basic apologies in advance

Comment: Could you check your console on the frontend for errors?

Comment: Yes, I just checked, but I don't know why it's all gray in the code snippet..

Comment: Have you included socket.io in the HTML file, please also check if the button click not returns an error, and that the server receives the product message (log it)?

Comment: Just a tip: IMO for what you are doing, AJAX would be a better solution. You don't need to have a WebSocketServer, plus it is easier to manually test the query you are sending to the server to ensure that the response is correct. Websockets are typically preferred for push communication (like chat) where the situation isn't request/response

Comment: Yes, the cdn.sicket.io is in the html file, i changed the "io.sockets.emit("products", data)" for a console.log(data) and is being passed correctly but its not showing on the html side so weird

Comment: @ControlAltDel I know, but i needed to practice websocket for a future test so this is what i got :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be the emitting method you are using on the server when receiving the `product` message from the client, it may be deprecated, so try to change it to another.

**Change this:**

```
io.sockets.emit("products", data);
```

**To:**

```
socket.emit("products", data);
```

**Or:**

```
io.emit("products", data);
```

You should use the local version of socket.io in the HTML file:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

For more information check the [Getting started guide](https://socket.io/get-started/chat#integrating-socketio) or the [Socket.IO emit cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emit-cheatsheet/).

Comment: tried all that but it still does not work, thanks for the links im going to give them a good look!

Comment: Check if the client received the data on the console, maybe it's some parsing problem.

Comment: Yes, the client is passing correclty the data but its not showing it on the html, if i do a console log of data instead of the emit it returns the 3 input.values perfectly :S

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the navigation when you submit the form using e.preventDefault();

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit("products", {
        title: title.value,
        price: price.value,
        thumbnail: thumbnail.value
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I had misspelled "products" in one of the emits and i was missing the e.preventDefault() too...

Comment: Glad you got it working, that was the first thing I checked... Should I keep/modify my answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! keep the answer, without that I would not have realized what was wrong with it =)